# For a simple circular motion is the tangential part of the momentum conserved in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

For simple circular motion in cartesian coordinates the angular momentum is conserved since the centripetal force has no torque to change it. Also the momentum is not conserved in any of the cartesian directions since the direction of force always directed towards the centre of the circle (the momentum vector is rotating).

But if I change to cylindrical coordinates then the momentum along the tangential direction must be conserved because at every point the force is perpendicular to the velocity, which is purely tangential. Is that the case? Is angular momentum conserved in that case too?

It surely cannot be right that in one coordinate system (cartesian) there works only one conservation law (angular momentum), and in other system (cylindrical) there are two conservation laws working (tangential momentum and angular momentum). So, I guess there should be something that is not working in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: The behaviour of the complete system does not depend what coordinate system you use to model it. The *mathematical expression* for the angular momentum will be different in cartesian and polar coordinates, but the reason it is conserved (or not) depends on the *physics*, not the math.

Comment: @sammygerbil I made a mistake in the title, thanks for noticing. I also added some structure to the question. I guess I intended to start a discussion from which all my additional questions would follow naturally.

Comment: @alephzero Thank you for your comment. That is exactly what I am trying to find out. Indeed, physics must be the same regardless of the coordinate system one chooses. But I am looking for a rigorous explanation of what exactly is conserved in cylindrical coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the answer by sammy gerbil, there are two conservation laws (momentum and angular momentum) that are true, whatever the coordinate system, under specific conditions (no external force or torque). However, you are on to something with your intuitive view.

If you study more advanced mechanics, you will learn about formulations of mechanics that differ from the vector formulation of Newton's laws. You can look up Hamiltonian mechanics for more details of one such formulation that is relevant here. Indeed, your observation that momentum along the tangential direction seems to behave like linear momentum in the system you mention is very astute. There is a concept called generalized coordinates in which, for example, an angle, is treated as the "basic" coordinate, and an expression gives a generalized momentum corresponding to this generalized coordinate. According to Noether's theorem, if a quantity called the action in a system is invariant with respect to some changes in one coordinate, then there is a corresponding conserved quantity corresponding to this coordinate. In your case, with a constrained circular motion, the action would be invariant under rotation and the momentum corresponding to angular position would be angular momentum as we usually understand it, which is the conserved quantity. So, in a sense, conservation of angular momentum is indeed conservation of momentum along the tangential direction for a particle constrained to move in a circle.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am familiar with more advanced mechanics, but, as you can see, I am not terribly good at it. That is what I suspected, but I wanted to find a proof that stems from more basic things. Somehow when I start looking at Euler-Lagrange equations, I loose all connections to physics and just treat everything as a math problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 laws of conservation here : angular momentum and linear momentum. Both are vectors.

Vectors are expressed differently in Cartesian and cylindrical co-ordinate systems. In a Cartesian system the components of linear momentum are constant in the absence of external forces; in a cylindrical system the components can change (unless the object is moving parallel to the axis).

Instantaneous tangential momentum as a vector is the same as linear momentum : $\vec{p}=m\vec{v}$. This changes in direction but not magnitude. So as a vector it is not conserved during uniform circular motion. This is the same as saying that in uniform circular motion the speed is constant but the velocity changes.

Tangential momentum measured about a point or axis is angular momentum : $\vec{L}=\vec{r} \times \vec{p}$. The direction of this vector (along the axis of rotation) does not change; neither does the magnitude. So as a vector it is conserved during uniform circular motion.

Changing the co-ordinate system does not change the laws of physics. Linear momentum remains linear in a cylindrical or spherical co-ordinate system. **Newton's 1st Law** remains true : in the absence of external forces bodies move in straight lines. They do not start moving in circles because someone changed their co-ordinate system.

Comment: Vectors are expressed differently in Cartesian and cylindrical co-ordinate systems. In a Cartesian system the components of linear momentum are constant in the absence of external forces; in a cylindrical system the components can change (unless the object is moving parallel to the axis). 
Do you refer here to an arbitrary motion? Because there is an external force in rotational motion.

Comment: I am referring to linear motion. In Cartesian co-ordinates this can be expressed with constant components, because the unit vectors are in a constant direction. Whereas in cylindrical co-ordinates the directions of the radial and tangential unit vectors change, so their components for linear motion change. It is not necessary to express linear motion using Cartesian co-ordinates and circular motion using cylindrical or spherical co-ordinates.

Comment: Linear motion is simple using Cartesian co-ordinates; circular motion is not. Conversely linear motion is awkward in cylindrical co-ordinates but circular motion is easy.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! May I also ask about the next part 
Instantaneous tangential momentum as a vector is the same as linear momentum. This changes in direction but not magnitude. I was referring to conservation of a component of momentum. The whole vector is clearly changing, but the tangential component must stay conserved. Just like if you throw a rock horizontally, only the component parallel to the ground would be conserved.

Comment: For the rock its linear velocity changes even though the horizontal component of that velocity is constant. In uniform circular motion the linear velocity changes even though the tangential component is constant. These components are constant for particular situations but in neither case is this a law of physics. Laws of physics are true in all reference frames and all situations.

Comment: But is conservation of momentum for even one coordinate not a valid physical law?

Comment: No, the conservation law applies to all co-ordinates, the whole vector, not individual components.

Comment: I see. But what if we write a Lagrangian for a horizontally thrown rock. That will consist of kinetic energies for x,y,z components - potential energy mgz. Then, there will be three Euler-Lagrange equations, and two of those (for x and y) will be nothing but conservation of momentum in these directions. So, this is how I understand it. What do you think ?

Comment: Sorry I am not confident answering questions about Euler-Lagrange equations, and do not want to engage in open-ended discussion. I recommend that you try the chatrooms.

Comment: I am not so confident myself. Thank you very much for your help anyways!